# In DialogFlow when date is displayed it come with YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS format how to convert to DD-MM-YYYY format?

Tags: dialogflow-es, sql-date-functions

The response given by the bot for date given by user for example 20th july is 2021-07-20T12:00:00+05:30. How to convert this to 2021-07-20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using the webhook we can do that. Here is some code reference.

Prerequisites:

- Create new intent and add a event like 'dateConverter'
- [image]
- Add response in newly created intent with Converted date: $date (Here in date we have formatted date)
- Enable the webhook for the intent for which date is being captured.
- Configured webhook in fulfillment section.

Here is the sample Node code.
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

```
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Starting server at ${port}`);
});

app.use(express.json())

app.post('/date-converter', async (req, res) => {
console.log("Dialogflow: Received a POST request");
if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
if (req.body.queryResult.parameters.hasOwnProperty('given-date')){
  let date = req.body.queryResult.parameters['given-date']
  let dateFormatter = date.split('T')[0].split("-").reverse().join("-");
  let responseObj = {
   "followupEventInput": {
     "name": "dateConverter",
     "parameters": {
      "date": dateFormatter
    }
   },
  "source": ""
  }
  return res.json(responseObj)
  }
  })
```

So when your main intent in which user has provided the date intent trigger then it'll call the webhook and convert the date format. After converting the date format it'll internally call the intent which has a event dateConverter with the specific parameter that we have defined in the webhook response.(Here we have define the **date**).

I think by using this we can convert the date from the YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS to DD-MM-YYYY or whatever format you want.

**NOTE:** For this sample user captured date should be stored in the given-date parameter. If you have different name then you need to change the name in the above code snippet.

Result:
[image]

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: I have two queries-
1. Have you created in default fallback intent or welcome intent
2. I didn't get about the code, where do I have to use it? Tried pasting in fulfillment tab but showing errors in it.

Comment: @IDK 1. No It's totally a new intent, you can say like fallbackEvent intent, Because I wanted to call it from the main intent. So we can store the converted date in the same dialogflow session. 

2. This is a webhook code, I started Node Application and created a REST API which can communicate with the dialogflow using the webhook (Use ngrok to communicate with local env. ).

Comment: Thanks.
I actually had created a restaurant bot so for reservation i had asked for date and time from the user, just now i saw that when I enter date and time together for the booking then the date is in normal format but if enter it separately then it doesn't work. For ex. suppose i say - Book a table for 7pm and then it asks what time? then i enter tomorrow then its coming with HH-MM-SS format. If i enter at one go like book for tomorrow at 7pm then it work fine in YYYY-MM-DD format.So any idea how to fix that?
Didnt get where to use code.I am a beginner,so pls tell exact location for code

Comment: Have you use the date-time or date and time entities. Can you please let me know? 

Regarding code, sure I'll create a small video and send it to you for your better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Dialogflow’s Inline Editor to extract the [date](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/system-entities#ex) part from the default date format that is provided by Dialogflow Essentials.
The [Inline Editor](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-inline-editor) uses Google Cloud Functions, so to use the Inline Editor you need to set up billing first.

You can refer to the below mentioned steps:

1. Create an Intent and add Training phrases to it and match entity types to **@sys.date** for date and **@sys.time** for time.
   [image]
2. Enable Fulfillment for that intent by clicking on the **“Enable webhook call for this intent”**
3. Go to the Fulfillment section and enable the Inline Editor.
4. Use the below mentioned code in the Inline Editor.

**Code:**

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }
 
  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
  
  function slot(agent){
    
    const time=agent.parameters.time.split(`T`)[1].split('+')[0];
    const date=agent.parameters.date.split(`T`)[0];
    agent.add(`your table is booked on  ` + date + ` ,`  + time);
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('hotel', slot);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

[image]

As we are using System entities for defining the date and time, System entities have their default formats.

So the value that we have extracted will not be shown in the parameters field as the entity for that parameter is defined with System entities.
However we can store the extracted values in our database.

Comment: Can we store the extracted date in the parameter? I think using fulfillment it's not possible right?

Comment: Thanks for the code and answer. I have query is it guaranteed that i wont be charged after the trial period is over

Comment: @IDK Dialogflow trial Edition is a free edition that provides most of the features of the standard ES agent type. It offers limited quota and support.
There are limits on the amount of requests that you can make in Trial Edition. For more details, see [Quotas & Limits](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas).

Comment: @IDK After your trial period ends you can upgrade to Dialogflow Essentials Edition.
If you use the built-in fulfillment editor, you will be using Google Cloud Functions which may incur charges. Dialogflow is priced monthly based on the edition and the requests made during the month.
You can refer to the [pricing table](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/pricing#es-agent) for editions, to create your own estimation depending on your needs.